# How to compute the Volume of a metric ball in a cylinder?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $C_R:=\mathbb{R}\times S^1_R$ be a $2$-dimensional cylinder of radius $R$ endowed with the standard Riemannian metric $g$. 
Pick an arbitrary point $p\in C_R$. How to compute the volume $\operatorname{Vol}_g^R(B_1(p))$, where $B_1(p)$ denotes the ball of radius $1$ in the metric space $(C_R,d_g)$ and $d_g$ is the canonical length metric coming from $g$.

The problem I am having is to find the correct integration boundaries using the area element. I.e. Use [Parametrization of cylinder and computation of area element in Lines 11-20](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder.html). Then one needs to compute the integral

$$ \int_{B_1(p)} dS = \int_?^? \int_0^1 R dx dy  . $$

How to proceed?